# Problems to control fan speed and keyboard lights in Asus TUF FX706HC

Tags: 22.04, asus, fancontrol, keyboard-backlight

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in my Asus TUF FX706HC and so far, so good, except I can't control the fan speed or change the colors of the lights of keyboard even though I can change their intensity. The BIOS doesn't give any option

I already tried: Rogauracore, OpenRGB and faustus without results.

https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore

http://openrgb.org/

https://github.com/hackbnw/faustus

I also tried:

```
sudo echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/fan-boost-mode
```

but I get:

```
bash: /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/fan-boost-mode: Permiso denegado
```

This doesn't work either (see: [How to control fans on an asus laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254364/how-to-control-fans-on-an-asus-laptop))

```
switch on = $ sudo echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm1_enable
switch off = $ sudo echo 2 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb wmi/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm1_enable
```

¿Ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, I have the same model of laptop and the issue of controlling lights and fans has been really frustrating. For the lights I found a suboptimal solution because having dual boot I can control them from Windows. Control of the fans can be done with Fn + F5 which gives three speed options. What I haven't been able to do is change the fan speed thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

switch on

> echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon[0]/pwm1_enable

switch off

> echo 2 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon[0]/pwm1_enable

[0] = check which is the name of your folder